# Best way to invalidate a number of memcache keys using standard php libraries?

Tags: php, caching, memcached

I have a database with files which can be searched, browsed and have multiple copies on multiple servers.

I cache searches, browse pages and server locations (urls). Say I delete a file, what's a good way to invalidate all searches, browse data and urls for this file? Or if a file server goes down, and I need to invalidate all urls pointing to this server?

Essentially I'm looking for something similar to [memcache-tags](https://code.google.com/p/memcached-tag/), but with standard memcache and php components. (Without having to change anything on the web server itself). I need some sort of many to many relation (one server has many files, and one file has multiple servers) in between keys, but can't seem to figure out a good way to accomplish this. In some situations stale cache is acceptable (minor updates etc.), but in some cases it's not (typically delete, and server down) where I need to invalidate all cache items containing references to it.

Some approaches I have looked at:

**[Namespaces](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#Deleting_by_Namespace)**:

```
$ns_key = $memcache->get("foo_namespace_key");
// if not set, initialize it
if($ns_key===false) $memcache->set("foo_namespace_key", rand(1, 10000));
// cleverly use the ns_key
$my_key = "foo_".$ns_key."_12345";
$my_val = $memcache->get($my_key);

//To clear the namespace do:
$memcache->increment("foo_namespace_key");
```

- Restricts the cache key to a single namespace

**[Item caching approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879657/whats-the-best-way-to-manage-keys-in-memcache-to-prevent-stale-cached-values)**:

```
$files = array('file1','file2');
// Cache all files as single entries
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $memcache->set($file.'_key');
}
$search = array('file1_key','file2_key');
// Retrieve all items found by search (typically cached as file ids)
foreach ($search as $item) {
  $memcache->get($item);
}
```

- Gives a problem if a file server is down, and all keys containing urls to this server should be invalidated (E.G large number of small cache items would be needed which in turn requires a large amount of requests against cache)- breaks any chance of caching full objects and resultsets

**[Tag implemenation](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-4253)**:

```
class KeyEnabled_Memcached extends Zend_Cache_Backend_Memcached
{

    private function getTagListId()
    {
        return "MyTagArrayCacheKey";
    }

    private function getTags()
    {
        if(!$tags = $this->_memcache->get($this->getTagListId()))
        {
            $tags = array();
        }
        return $tags;
    }

    private function saveTags($id, $tags)
    {
        // First get the tags
        $siteTags = $this->getTags();

        foreach($tags as $tag)
        {
            $siteTags[$tag][] = $id;
        }
        $this->_memcache->set($this->getTagListId(), $siteTags);        
    }

    private function getItemsByTag($tag)
    {
        $siteTags = $this->_memcache->get($this->getTagListId());
        return isset($siteTags[$tag]) ? $siteTags[$tag] : false;
    }

    /**
     * Save some string datas into a cache record
     *
     * Note : $data is always "string" (serialization is done by the
     * core not by the backend)
     *
     * @param  string $data             Datas to cache
     * @param  string $id               Cache id
     * @param  array  $tags             Array of strings, the cache record will be tagged by each string entry
     * @param  int    $specificLifetime If != false, set a specific lifetime for this cache record (null => infinite lifetime)
     * @return boolean True if no problem
     */
    public function save($data, $id, $tags = array(), $specificLifetime = false)
    {
        $lifetime = $this->getLifetime($specificLifetime);
        if ($this->_options['compression']) {
            $flag = MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED;
        } else {
            $flag = 0;
        }
        $result = $this->_memcache->set($id, array($data, time()), $flag, $lifetime);
        if (count($tags) > 0) {
            $this->saveTags($id, $tags);
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Clean some cache records
     *
     * Available modes are :
     * 'all' (default)  => remove all cache entries ($tags is not used)
     * 'old'            => remove too old cache entries ($tags is not used)
     * 'matchingTag'    => remove cache entries matching all given tags
     *                     ($tags can be an array of strings or a single string)
     * 'notMatchingTag' => remove cache entries not matching one of the given tags
     *                     ($tags can be an array of strings or a single string)
     *
     * @param  string $mode Clean mode
     * @param  array  $tags Array of tags
     * @return boolean True if no problem
     */
    public function clean($mode = Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL, $tags = array())
    {
        if ($mode==Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_ALL) {
            return $this->_memcache->flush();
        }
        if ($mode==Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_OLD) {
            $this->_log("Zend_Cache_Backend_Memcached::clean() : CLEANING_MODE_OLD is unsupported by the Memcached backend");
        }
        if ($mode==Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_TAG) {
            $siteTags = $newTags = $this->getTags();
            if(count($siteTags))
            {
                foreach($tags as $tag)
                {
                    if(isset($siteTags[$tag]))
                    {
                        foreach($siteTags[$tag] as $item)
                        {
                            // We call delete directly here because the ID in the cache is already specific for this site
                            $this->_memcache->delete($item);
                        }
                        unset($newTags[$tag]);
                    }
                }
                $this->_memcache->set($this->getTagListId(),$newTags);
            }
        }
        if ($mode==Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_NOT_MATCHING_TAG) {
            $siteTags = $newTags = $this->getTags();
            if(count($siteTags))
            {
                foreach($siteTags as $siteTag => $items)
                {
                    if(array_search($siteTag,$tags) === false)
                    {
                        foreach($items as $item)
                        {
                            $this->_memcache->delete($item);
                        }
                        unset($newTags[$siteTag]);
                    }
                }
                $this->_memcache->set($this->getTagListId(),$newTags);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- No control over what keys are invalidated when, due to internal memcache key dropping, can drop a tag key which in turn invalidate a large number of actual valid keys (which would still exist)
- Issues with write concurrency

**[Two-step cache system](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.backends.html#zend.cache.backends.twolevels)**:

```
// Having one slow, and one fast cache mechanism where the slow cache is reliable storage  containing a copy of tag versions 
$cache_using_file['tag1'] = 'version1';
$cache_using_memcache['key'] = array('data' = 'abc', 'tags' => array('tag1' => 'version1');
```

- Potential bottleneck using disk/mysql etc. for the slow cache
- Issues with write concurrency

Comment: I'm a fanboy for namespacing.  Also remember, keys can be 250 characters long, so if you have a programmatic way of generating namespaces you can tack on multiple namespace's in front of a key.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322709/php-memcache-design-patterns

Comment: Please note David's comment - you can attach multiple namespaces, eg: cache key for some product with id pid1235 for country countrycode1235  can be  pid1235_PRODUCTVERSION_x_countrycode1235_COUNTRYVERSION_y. 

In this example, there are two versions: PRODUCTVERSION_x and COUNTRYVERSION_y. You can invalidate key by changing x (if product data changes) and y(if country-related data changes and you logic requires product invalidation).

Comment: Hi Jon!, I have same problem here. Workaround using tags for invalidation with Memchached (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162415/how-to-selectively-clear-cache-using-tags-or-other-option-with-memchached-back).

I like very much your KeyEnabled_Memcached class. However, It's a long time since you published your question so I'd like to know if there is any update I should know before including your class in my code. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having come accross the comment [here](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/issues/detail?id=189), which explains the logic of evicting existing keys, I believe tags can be implemented reliable by the version flags approach mentioned in: [PHP memcache design patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322709/php-memcache-design-patterns)

I actually implemented this logic once already, but discarded it as unreliable due to memcache eviction of elements before they expire. You can find my initial implementation [here](https://code.google.com/p/memcached-tag/). I do however, believe this is a reliable tags pattern because:

- On cache object retrieval, the object is moved on top of the LRU stack
- All tags/flags are retrieved right after the cache object
- If a flag is evicted, any item containing this flag would have been evicted just before
- Incrementing a flag returns the new value in the same operation, avoiding write concurrency. If a second thread is incrementing the same flag before the cache object is written, it is by definition invalid already

Please correct me if I'm wrong! :-)

Answer (score 0):

See [Organizing memcache keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510759/organizing-memcache-keys/2723381#2723381)

Unless you can "master key" items, there's no sane way to do this. By this I mean something like "user4231-is_valid". You could check that for anything that used that user's data. Otherwise, unless you're tracking everything that references your file in question, you can't invalidate all of them. If you do that, you still have to iterate all possibilities in order to successfully delete.

Document your dependencies, limit your dependencies, track your dependencies in your code for deletion activities.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with memcached, but I understand that IO are cheap there.

I'd go with your tag implementation, make sure the tag list is used frequently and hope that the internal mmcd' logic would "think" that it's something too busy to be dropped :)

Comment: You can make it "fuzzy" with some random sanity tests and invalidate more then needed when you find inconsistency...