# How to selectively clear cache (using tags or other option) with Memchached backend and Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, caching, memcached, zend-cache

We use Memcached and Zend Framework in our web project. Now, we need to clean cache selectively using tags as specified in [Zend_Cache API](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.cache.theory.html#zend.cache.tags).

Unfortunately, [memcached doesn't support tags](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.cache.backends.html#zend.cache.backends.memcached).

I have found these workarounds:

- [Memcached-tag project](http://code.google.com/p/memcached-tag/). Has anybody tested it? How to implement it with Zend?
- Use wildchards like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595904/memcache-and-wildcards), but it seems a bit confusing, less transparent and harder to implement with Zend.
- Use [this implementation](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-4253) or [this one](https://github.com/bigwhoop/taggable-zend-memcached-backend/blob/master/src/TrekkSoft/Cache/TaggableZendMemcachedBackend.php), for supporting tags in Memcached, beeing aware of the drawbacks.
- Any other option?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You're right. Memcache don't support tags.

You can use another key-value to implement tag for memcache.

EX :

```
$this->objCache->save($arrResults, $strKey,array($strMyTag),$intCacheTime) // note : array($strMyTag) don't work for Memcache

MemcacheTag::setTag($strKey, $strMyTag) // our work around
```

About setTag Method & MemcacheTag:

```
function setTag($strKey,$strTag){

    $arrKey  = $cacheOjb->get($strTag);

    $arrKey[]= $strKey; 

}

function deleteCacheWithTag($strTag){

    $arrKey  = $cacheOjb->get($strTag);

    foreach ($arrKey as $strKey){

       $objCache->delete($strKey);

    }

}
```

This work around is quite simple and it works for my projects.

*Note: these codes need some modification, sorry for posting in a hurry